# Geolocate control triggered before added to a map in react-map-gl

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation, mapbox, react-map-gl

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import Map, { GeolocateControl, Marker } from "react-map-gl";
import "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css";

const App = () => {
  const map = useRef(null);
  const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([]);
  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    latitude: 13.084547176887455,
    longitude: 79.95072330224205,
    width: "100vw",
    height: "100vh",
    zoom: 13,
  });
  const geolocateControlRef = useCallback((ref) => {
    console.log(ref);
    if (ref) {
      ref.trigger();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="h-screen">
      <Map
        ref={map}
        className="h-full"
        initialViewState={viewport}
        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11"
        mapboxAccessToken="pk.eyJ1IjoibmF2ZWVuZzI0MDIiLCJhIjoiY2w1dTlya29xMDl4cjNrdGZ1OWszNTY3aiJ9.ijW4t9ROw0Pa-Uyhgv2s6Q"
        onClick={(e) => setMarkers([...markers, e.lngLat])}
      >
        {map.current && (
          <GeolocateControl ref={geolocateControlRef}></GeolocateControl>
        )}
        {markers.map((marker, i) => (
          <Marker key={i} latitude={marker.lat} longitude={marker.lng}></Marker>
        ))}
      </Map>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I'm trying to show the user location on the map and from the docs I came to know about the **GeolocateControl** tag but it fails

This comes straight off the documentation but it yells!!!
[image: Chrome DevTools Error Log]

The map is showing fine and it is at the initial position
[image: Image showing the map]

Answer (score 0):

As a (somewhat ugly) workaround I edited the `geolocateControlRef` to look like this.

```js
const geolocateControlRef = useCallback((ref) => {
  if (ref) {
    (async () => {
      while (!map.current) await ((() => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 200)))())
      ref.trigger();
    })()
  }
}, []);
```

Basically this checks every 100ms if map ref is truthy (=loaded). And if it is, try triggering geolocateControl.

I'm still getting the same error message for some reason, but at least the functionality is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onLoad` method in yours `Map` component. By setting boolean to true in the created `useState`, you can solve this problem.